# How to have custom namespace prefix

Tags: jaxb

I am new to JAXB. I am able to populate the XML. In my case I need my namespace prefix  as

```
<set xmlns="www.google.com"
   xmlns:myName="www.google.com">
```

instead of

```
<set xmlns="www.google.com"
   xmlns:ns2="www.google.com">
```

I have used `package-info` class and also the `@XmlType` annotation. Do I need to add any variable to get the desired name for the second namespace like "xmlns:MyName' instead of "xmlns:ns2"?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your JAXB provider or a recent version of the JAXB RI then you can do the following:

**package-info**

You can use the `@XmlNs` annotation on the `xmlns` property of the `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the prefix for a namespace.

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="www.google.com",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "www.google.com", prefix = ""),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "www.google.com", prefix = "myName"),
    })
package forum13817126;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Java Model**

Below is a simple Java model that I will use for this example.

```java
package forum13817126;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Set {

}
```

**Demo Code**

The following demo code will create an instance of the domain model and marshal it to XML.

```java
package forum13817126;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Set.class);

        Set set = new Set();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(set, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myName:set xmlns="www.google.com" xmlns:myName="www.google.com"/>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: I have tried using XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.org/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/0.9", xmlns = { @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://www.xxxxx.org/xxxxx/xxxxxx/0.9"), @XmlNs(prefix = "image", namespaceURI = "http://www.yyyyyy.com/yyyyyy/yyyyy-yyyy/1.1") }, elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED), still i am getting the default ns2 prefix.I tried to class extending NamespacePrefixMapper, but i am getting javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: this exception i am using jre 6, tomcat 6.0.35 and jaxb-api-2.2.6.jar

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `xmlns` property on the `@XmlSchema` annotation in `package-info`. Its value is an array of annotations giving suggested prefix mappings for the marshaller. While it is technically allowed to ignore these suggestions I find they are usually respected as long as there are no clashes (two different packages suggesting the same prefix for different URIs).

Comment: +1 - I have included a full example in my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13818022/383861