# Custom name space JAXB, XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to map following xml using custom name sapace. I checked [How to have custom namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817126/how-to-have-custom-namespace-prefix) but could not find any answer.

```
<p385:execute xmlns:p385="http://tal.myserver.com">
<version xsi:type="xsd:string">0.1.0</version>
<xmlData xsi:type="xsd:string">
   .... xml encoded data
</xmlData>
</p385:execute>
```

How can i map this to a java class?

Comment: No i donot have any XSD i am trying to upgrade a java 1.4 Webservice application to java 1.6. the code block above is inside a soap envolope and envolope is signed.

Comment: ? I assume you have a WSDL then, which embeds or references the XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is only the root element that is namespace qualified, you just need to specify the namespace on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation for the class.

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://tal.myserver.com")
public class Execute {
}
```

You can the suggest the prefix that should be used for the namespace using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the wsimport tool to generate artifacts such as JAXB classes from a WSDL:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html